# Memory leak in disconnected mode

Tags: jss

I have a global footer referencing other items (yml files), which is referencing to the same footer, resulting in too big string to parse.

This wasn't a problem in TP4, but I noticed that I get a `layout` property on the referenced item.

Here's my global footer:

```
id: component-footer
componentName: Footer
fields:
  about: # FieldType: ContentList
 - id: media-services-page
 - id: sponsors-and-partners-page
 - id: governances-page
 - id: jobs-page
 - id: contact-us-page
```

I get this error when running `npm start`.

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000001286BA257C1 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: parse(this=000001286BA08FF1 <Object map = 00000250BCD82BA1>,0000001DCD7AE509 <Very long string[206909388]>)

    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [C:\Git\jss-dc-error\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-manifest\dist\generator\pipelines\generateManifest\expandReferencedContent.js:18] [bytecode=0000009390F063C9 offset=88](this=00000237643822D1 <undefined>,i...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString
 5: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
 6: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts
 7: v8_inspector::protocol::Debugger::API::SearchMatch::fromJSONString
 8: v8_inspector::protocol::Debugger::API::SearchMatch::fromJSONString
 9: 00000085D2986B21
```

I have created a repository for you to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/jeppeskovsen/jss-dc-error (see second commit)

Can I shorten the `layout` property? Or how would you suggest I fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify this question further? I'm not sure what's being asked or how a memory leak is involved?

Comment: I have updated the description :)

Comment: Not really an answer but I've brought this into the issue tracker for investigation. Thanks for the reproduction repo :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar out-of- memory error when performing a `jss deploy app -c -d`.  After spending much of the day digging through logs and JSS source code, I found out the problem is really that Node.JS has a default memory limit of 512 MB, which was getting hit during our deploy as we use Typescript and Webpack which consume quite a bit of memory.  Node JS has an parameter you can pass it to change the memory limit, but since the command to start Node is hidden under several layers (i.e. Sitecore and React-Script) the easiest way to increase the limit is to set an environment variable that increases the limit of for all Node.js applications on the server.  This is the Powershell command I used in the Docker container hosting Sitecore to increase the limit from 512MB to 4GB
`$Env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096"`